# How do I merge array with json data? php, laravel

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I have this json data:

```
"{"media_ids":[304,305,306]}"
```

and my array :

```
 { ["media_ids"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(388) [1]=> int(389) } }
```

I attempted to merge them by doing this

```
$allData = array_merge($extra,json_decode($a,true));
```

But the result was my array data disappeared:

```
{ ["media_ids"]=> array(3) { [0]=> int(304) [1]=> int(305) [2]=> int(306) } }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use array_merge_recursive

```
$allData = array_merge_recursive($extra,json_decode($a,true));
```